# why react-query fetchNextPage not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I'm trying to make an infinite scrolling functionality with `useInfiniteQuery` but every time I call `fetchNextPage` it just refetch the first page. I check everywhere on react-query docs and check my code line by line but nothing works.

here's the code

```
const fetchData = async ({ pageParams = 1 }) => {
    const res = axios.get(
      `https://uniplato.staging.uniplato.us/api/v1/mock-data?page=${pageParams}`,
    )
    return res
  }

  const {
    isLoading,
    data,
    error,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(['posts'], fetchData, {
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
      console.log('data = ', lastPage.data.data)
      const nextPage = lastPage.data.data.limit + 1 ?? undefined
      return nextPage
    },
  })
```

Comment: it's `pageParam` not `pageParams`. Also, please log `nextPage` before you return it. Very likely, it is just `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing PageParam argument to fetchData inside useInfiniteQuery.

Wrap fetchData in an arrow function where you also set starting value:

```
const fetchData = async (pageParams) => {
    const res = axios.get(
      `https://uniplato.staging.uniplato.us/api/v1/mock-data?page=${pageParams}`,
    )
    return res
  }

  const {
    isLoading,
    data,
    error,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(['posts'], ({pageParam = 1}) => fetchData(pageParam), {
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
      console.log('data = ', lastPage.data.data)
      return lastPage.data.hasNextPage ? lastPage.data.page + 1 : undefined
    },
  })
```

Comment: This didn't work, just return same page over and over. checked the lastPage and it's returning the number of next page but still getting same page.

Comment: @emhossein, I checked what the api returns, you should use lastPage.data.page to calculate the number of the next page. Limit is the number of entities you get in each page. It's 10 by default so you always get page number 11